# How to send silent push to iOS via Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push, google-cloud-messaging

How to send silent push notification to iOS application over GCM?

Silent push is notification that will not appear in notification center, but awake application to do some action in background.
Google introduce new features in new [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) with possibility to send push messages to Android, Chrome and iOS.

Any idea, how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `content_available` (not `content-available`) attribute like this:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Authorization:key=AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" --data-ascii '{"data":{"xxx":"yyy"},"content_available":true,"to":"XXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY-ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"}'
```

Comment: @black_stallion https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref search for content_available

Answer (score 4):

From your server, you'll need to add the `content-available` property with a value of 1 to your `aps` dictionary.

You'll need to provide support for these silent notifications by adding `remote-notification` to `UIBackgroundModes` in your Info.plist file. More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [node-gcm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm) npm library and the following payload works for me for iOS (for Android I'm sending a slightly different payload):

```
{ dryRun: false,
  data: 
   { customKey1: 'CustomValue1',
     customKey2: 'CustomValue2',
     content_available: '1',
     priority: 'high' },
  notification: 
   { title: 'My Title',
     icon: 'ic_launcher',
     body: 'My Body',
     sound: 'default',
     badge: '2' } }
```

Of course you'll need to ensure that your app can handle the inbound notification.