# Push notification with GCM on ios

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to do as Koh suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616302/how-to-send-silent-push-to-ios-via-google-cloud-messaging/30752004), my problem is that when I send this JSON :

```
{
    "to": "/topics/test",
    "data": {
        "aps" : {
            "alert" : "You got your emails."
        }
    }
}
```

But the notification I receive is :

```
Notification received: {
    aps = "{\"alert\":\"You got your emails.\"}";
    "collapse_key" = "do_not_collapse";
    from = "/topics/test";
}
```

It seems that the JSON aps is changed to a simple string before I receive it.
Is there a way to get the proper notification syntax so that my app recognize it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "notification" field instead of "data".

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref

Comment: When I do that, nothing happens. I mean, I don't even go through the [AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:] method.

Comment: Did you tried like this?:

{ "notification": {
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "body": "5 to 1"
  },
  "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."
}

Comment: this works, with this model, can you link to the documentation where it is explained?

Comment: Sure! Added it into my answer