# GCM works fine on Android but not working on iOS

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I've succefuly implemented the GCM for android but when I tried to implement it to my iOS version I won't get the push messages.

I got my gcm token at the iOS version, and could sent messages (I used Postman).
I got a succesful response and a unique message ID but no push recieved. I've been struggling with this for few days.

i tried to create a new GCm project and also running the GCM examples for iOS but nothing works.

I'm using the same account for iOS and Android with same apiKey ofcourse.

Postman code:

```
{
          "collapse_key": "score_update",
          "time_to_live": 108,
          "delay_while_idle": true,
          "data": {
            "score": "4x8",
            "time": "15:16.2342"
          },
          "registration_ids":["My Token"],
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: post the code you are using for the GCM HTTP or XMPP request

Comment: added postman code for sending the message

Comment: hey juvi can you share your gcm code for android??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unbelievable, had to change "data" with "notification".
The payload for iOS is bit different. More info can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#payload)

Comment: I was about to suggest that. The notification payload works better on iOS and the data payload works better on Android.

Comment: so I'll have to check which platform the user using before sending the request?

Comment: Yes. When you register the user, make sure you grab the OS field too.

Comment: are you sure? when I try it I get `"error": "InvalidParameters"`

Comment: make sure your token is valid

Comment: @Juvi it is. When i use `data` i get a 200 success, but the message isn't received on the device

Comment: Are you working on android device? if you do it's issue with the implementation of the receiver. I suggest you follow the guide,it's kinda clear...

Comment: @Juvi no, the android client works fine. Problem is with the ios client

Comment: @Juvi IOS randomly work but Android is working always. is it the case with you?

Comment: @TarekEl-Mallah what is the reason for that random misbehaviour??Have you got it corrected?

Comment: @abhi1992 First reason was the certificate, and the way you build the application , if build for development certificate you should use the sandbox flag. and if production or Ah Hoc you should not use sandbox and use the production certificate.
second please check my answer above, it contain note regarding the "priority":"high" attribute.

Comment: The data payload and notification payload are both applicable on iOS & Android. On iOS the difference is that notification payload is sent through APNS while data payload is sent through GCM's own connection which is only there when app is in foreground. SO,If I want to use GCM in both android and ios,the payload should contain only notification?or is both data and notification is fine?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and it's fixed by using content_available and priority options as shown in below documentation:

You should send **"content_available":true**, and **"priority":"high",**

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

[image]

Sample JSON request:

```
{
  "content_available":true,
  "to":"fd4...23f7",
  "priority":"high",
  "notification":
    {
    "body":"anything",
    "title":"any title"
    }
}
```