# Data payload not being handled on Android when using `content_available`

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a payload using GCM that can be handled **on the background or foreground** by clients using **Android and iOS**. The messages are delivered to clients using both platforms that are subscribed in a topic.

Because I need the iOS app to handle the data even when the app is on the background or closed, I'm setting `"content_available": true`, which works as expected on iOS.

However, when I add that parameter, Android does not handle the received data and instead displays a blank notification.

Here's an example payload:

```
{
   "to": "/topics/946",
   "content_available": true,
   "data": {
      "time": "2016-02-04 18:33:08",
      "message": "Hello",
      "msgType": "chat",
      "senderId": "50",
      "senderName": "John"
   }
}
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) says that data messages should wake the Android app anyway:

> On iOS, use this field to represent `content-available` in the APNS
>   payload. When a notification or message is sent and this is set to
>   `true`, an inactive client app is awoken. On Android, data messages wake
>   the app by default. On Chrome, currently not supported.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've already tried using `"priority":"high"`, which does not make any difference.

Comment: You may set a parameter **`"priority":"high"`**. When a message is sent with high priority, it is sent immediately, and the app can wake a sleeping device and open a network connection to your server. Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408313/gcm-works-fine-on-android-but-not-working-on-ios).

Comment: @abielita I tried using the `priority` parameter, which makes no difference. About the other question, my problem is the opposite - it works with iOS and not Android.

Comment: Apparently this is an open issue with GCM: https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/63