# Gcm IOS notification not receiving

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

few days ago push notifications (gcm) stop receive on my ios application

i send request with data :

```
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("registration_ids", ids);
    Map<String, T> request = new HashMap<String, T>();
    request.put("message", message);
    data.put("data", request);
    data.put("notification", notificationPayload);
    data.put("content_available", true);
    data.put("priority", "high");
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Authorization", "key=" + googleApiKey);
```

ids not empty and correct, other data correct too .
But in response from gcm i start receive this error **Invalid parameters**

Which parameter can be invalid, few days ago it worked

Thanks

Comment: First, make sure that the token are you using is valid. You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#obtain_a_registration_token) for that. Second, make sure that the key that you use is SERVER key. For more information, you can check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408313/gcm-works-fine-on-android-but-not-working-on-ios).

Comment: Thanks, problem in big payload .