# GCM push notifications not working for iOS when the app is not active

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have enabled the background modes in xcode and checked "Remote notifications".

Do I have to enable "Push Notifications" too? for GCM

here is the payload from my rest client

```
{
    "data": {


            "displayMessage": {
                "message": "Package delivered",

            }

    },
    "registration_ids": [
        "dgfdghdfghgfhhfjhgjghjghjhjghjghjghjghjghjghjhgggh"
    ],
    "content-available" : true,
    "priority": "high"
}
```

This works when the app is in foreground and does not work when the app is not in foreground.

Any help to get this GCM for ios working would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this question though
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192145/gcm-push-notification-when-ios-app-is-in-the-background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM Notifications not receiving when app is in background mode in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704736/gcm-notifications-not-receiving-when-app-is-in-background-mode-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the format of the message as it is mentioned here :

[Making GCM work for iOS device in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109514/making-gcm-work-for-ios-device-in-the-background)

Comment: I have tried that before posting this question with no success. Can you think of anything else that I might be missing?

Comment: i suppose it is related to the server side not client, can you provide some code to show how you make requests to GCM? @SanthoshAdari

Comment: I just user rest client called "Advanced Rest Client" for google chrome

Comment: {
  "to": "dfgdfgdfgdfc:APA91bGAmf3utL-k3BaZtzVXYayceu6XfW28ewdsgdgdfgdfhgdfgdf86zxxVyi9sIvJqRBZxz18-6PzZxjDeX_Bdn-ZmXaeTslB8qCGsH4m79iUK1bueN2bzTpQ3tx",
  "data": {
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": "2",
    "title": "default",
    "body": "Test Push!"
  },
"content-available":true
}

Comment: i get Internal server error when i use "notification" instead of "data". with "data" i can open notification when app is active.

Comment: You can use `notification` and `data` together.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is wrong. Use `content_available`, not `content-available`.

Also, your JSON is invalid. Specifically, this:

`"message": "Package delivered",`

should not have a comma at the end.

Comment: content_available would always give me "InternalServerError". I have read the documentation and I agree that it asks us to use content_available for gcm.

Comment: I'm using GCM to push to iOS devices, it's working for me. I'm using content_available.

Comment: can you let me know what rest client are you using?

Comment: the response is always `{
multicast_id: 6973668141157543000
success: 0
failure: 1
canonical_ids: 0
results: [1]
0:  {
error: "InternalServerError"
}-
-
}` when i use content_available. however when i use content-available it won't wake up the app.

Comment: Is the HTTP response also a 5xx error? If so, the docs says to contact the android-gcm group to report the error. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref  The group URL is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-gcm

Comment: Oh, you know what. You also have a syntax error in your JSON because you have a comma after "Package delivered". Remove the comma and try again. Updated answer to include this part.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Doug Richardson. It was just a copy paste error.my payload looks like this and still can't get it working.`{
  "to": "lTgMVojkkjhjgkikkaxdFbeCp0ti6j8W9V3aPMs_bZ7nIhAzpu6jyGK-St2lb8ANdE9uuopopnH1Hyuuiuiuiuiui3wnKJHNDulehzZzkRRbt4MShCdJkTLo",
 
"content_available":true,
"data":{
"displayMessage":"Hello world"
}
}'

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred from server side. Notification message body should be like this.

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "content_available" : "true"
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
    }
}
```

Here is the code that I have implemented and working fine.

```
<?php

// Message to send
$notificationTitle = "Notification title";
$notificationtBody  = "Notification arrived";

$registrationId = 'GCM_DEVICE_TOKEN';
$apiKey = "GCM_SERVER_KEY";

$response = sendNotification( 
                $apiKey, 
                $registrationId, 
                array(  
                    'sound' => "default", 
                    'badge' => 1, 
                    'body' => $notificationtBody,
                    'title' => $notificationTitle
                )
            );              

echo $response;


function sendNotification( $apiKey, $registrationId, $messageData )
{   
    $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" . $apiKey);
    $data = array(
        'to' => $registrationId,
        'content_available' => true,
        'notification' => $messageData
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This notification worked for me

```
{
  "to":"ID",
  "notification":{  
    "sound":"default",
    "title":"TITLE",
    "body":"BODY"
  },
  "priority": "high"
}
```