# GCM Push Notifications are not coming on iPhone when app is not active for one day

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

On iPhone/iPad after installing the app, app is able to receive notification first time. Once app is inactive, then it stops getting notification in both foreground and background.

Can someone point, what I am I missing . Looks like no issue with message format since I get first time.

Server Code:

```
            message.put("priority", "high");
            message.put("content_available",true);
            if (to != null)
            {
                message.put("to", to.replace("\\", ""));
            }
            if (messageId != null)
            {
                message.put("message_id", messageId);
            }
            JSONObject subobj = new JSONObject();
            subobj.put("sound", "default");
            message.put("notification", subobj);

            message.put("data", payload);
            if (timeToLive != null)
            {
                message.put("time_to_live", timeToLive);
            }
            if (delayWhileIdle != null && delayWhileIdle)
            {
                message.put("delay_while_idle", true);
            }
            if (collapseKey != null)
            {
                message.put("collapse_key", collapseKey);
            }
            message.put("delivery_receipt_requested", true);
```

Client Code:

```
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

{

```
// First run Delete keychain

if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirstRun"]) {
    // Delete values from keychain here

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [self resetKeychain];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1strun" forKey:@"FirstRun"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];


CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
#else
   self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] 
autorelease];
#endif
self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
//notification

[self updateDurationLabel];
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[self.segFromStyle setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.segToStyle setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self flowManager];


UILocalNotification *remoteNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (remoteNotification) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    self.launchNotification = remoteNotification.userInfo;

    NSLog(@"NotificationCheck: remoteNotification");

}

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if (localNotification) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSLog(@"NotificationCheck: localNotification");

    self.launchNotification = localNotification.userInfo;

    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:localNotification.userInfo options:0 error:nil];
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Dict:%@", jsonString);
      }
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192145/gcm-push-notification-when-ios-app-is-in-the-background) wherein it suggested to add the `"priority": "high"` to the JSON toget the notifications in the background.

```
{
  "to" : "token...",
  "priority": "high",
  "notification" : {
    "title": "GCM TITLE",
    "body" : "FROM GCM",
    "badge": "1",
    "sound": "default"
  }
}
```

Additional references:

- [GCM push notification to iOS with content_available (not working to invoke from inactive state)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893152/gcm-push-notification-to-ios-with-content-available-not-working-to-invoke-from)
- [GCM support for ios application when application in background or killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883607/gcm-support-for-ios-application-when-application-in-background-or-killed)
- [Making GCM work for iOS device in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109514/making-gcm-work-for-ios-device-in-the-background)

Comment: Thanks for response. I do have set  priority and content_available flags already. [message.put("priority", "high");  message.put("content_available",true);]                                                               Only flag missing in code is 'badge', let me try my luck with it.