# Implement push notification in IOs using GCM

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the Google Cloud Messaging. And i receive the notifications. But i dont know how to convert it to push notification. Can anyone help me with this? I am getting this result from GCM   **Notification received: [message: Simon Swiped yes for your profile, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, from: 857170554763]**

Here is the code.Can anyone help me with this?

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,    GGLInstanceIDDelegate, GCMReceiverDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var connectedToGCM = false
var subscribedToTopic = false
var gcmSenderID: String?
var registrationToken: String?
var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()

let registrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"
let messageKey = "onMessageReceived"
let subscriptionTopic = "/topics/global"

// [START register_for_remote_notifications]
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
[NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
// [START_EXCLUDE]
// Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
// the services that have entries in the file
var configureError:NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
// [END_EXCLUDE]
// Register for remote notifications
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
    UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
  application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
} else {
  // Fallback
  let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
  application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
}

// [END register_for_remote_notifications]
// [START start_gcm_service]
let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)
// [END start_gcm_service]
return true
}

func subscribeToTopic() {
// If the app has a registration token and is connected to GCM, proceed to subscribe to the
// topic
if(registrationToken != nil && connectedToGCM) {
  GCMPubSub.sharedInstance().subscribeWithToken(self.registrationToken, topic: subscriptionTopic,
                                                options: nil, handler: {(error:NSError?) -> Void in
                                                  if let error = error {
                                                    // Treat the "already subscribed" error more gently
                                                    if error.code == 3001 {
                                                      print("Already subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)")
                                                    } else {
                                                      print("Subscription failed: \(error.localizedDescription)");
                                                    }
                                                  } else {
                                                    self.subscribedToTopic = true;
                                                    NSLog("Subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)");
                                                  }
  })
}
}

// [START connect_gcm_service]
func applicationDidBecomeActive( application: UIApplication) {
// Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({(error:NSError?) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  } else {
    self.connectedToGCM = true
    print("Connected to GCM")
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    self.subscribeToTopic()
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
  }
})
}
// [END connect_gcm_service]

// [START disconnect_gcm_service]
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
// [START_EXCLUDE]
self.connectedToGCM = false
// [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END disconnect_gcm_service]

// [START receive_apns_token]
func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
deviceToken: NSData ) {
// [END receive_apns_token]
// [START get_gcm_reg_token]
// Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
// Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
// token to enable reception of notifications
GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                       kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
                                                         scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
// [END get_gcm_reg_token]
}

// [START receive_apns_token_error]
func application( application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
error: NSError ) {
print("Registration for remote notification failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
// [END receive_apns_token_error]
let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
  registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}

// [START ack_message_reception]
func application( application: UIApplication,
                didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
// This works only if the app started the GCM service
GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
// Handle the received message
// [START_EXCLUDE]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                                                          userInfo: userInfo)
// [END_EXCLUDE]
}

func application( application: UIApplication,
                didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                                             fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
// This works only if the app started the GCM service
GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
// Handle the received message
// Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
// [START_EXCLUDE]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                                                          userInfo: userInfo)
handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
// [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END ack_message_reception]

func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
if (registrationToken != nil) {
  self.registrationToken = registrationToken
  print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
  self.subscribeToTopic()
  let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
    self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
} else {
  print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
    self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
}

// [START on_token_refresh]
func onTokenRefresh() {
// A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
                                                         scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
}
// [END on_token_refresh]

// [START upstream_callbacks]
func willSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!, error: NSError!) {
if (error != nil) {
  // Failed to send the message.
} else {
  // Will send message, you can save the messageID to track the message
}
}

func didSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!) {
// Did successfully send message identified by messageID
}
 // [END upstream_callbacks]

func didDeleteMessagesOnServer() {
// Some messages sent to this device were deleted on the GCM server before reception, likely
// because the TTL expired. The client should notify the app server of this, so that the app
// server can resend those messages.
}

 }
```

Comment: notification != push notification ? what is your actual question ?

Comment: I have to show the message as a push notification in iphone's notification bar @Shubhank

Comment: they only come when app is in background. In foreground - you can simply show a alert if you want.

Comment: it doesn't work when the app is in background

Comment: your code is very poorly formatted. I don't think anyone will go over it plus your question is also not clear. You could have asked i am not getting notification but you ask to show notification which is wrong to ask.

Comment: oh i'm sorry. i'm a newbie to stack overflow.. the push notification is not working in background

Answer (score 1):

Found this on the [GCM Notifications docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

> If you want to send messages consisting of only custom key/values to
>   an iOS device when the app is in the background, set custom key/value
>   pairs in data and set `"content_available"` to true. It seems that
>   maybe the missing part of your code.

sample:

```
 {
  "to": "gcm_token_of_the_device",
  "content_available":true,
  "notification": {
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": "2",
    "title": "default",
    "body": "Test Push!"
  }
}
```

You can also check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109514/making-gcm-work-for-ios-device-in-the-background) for additional insight.