# Can't able to receive GCM Messages in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I am able to register my device with backend using GCM Registration ID.But I am not able to receive GCM message in my iPad/iPhone, even though the server(.NET) got success message. And I am able to receive the notification when sending through a third party tool called APN Tester. I am not able to find what must be the problem for this. And I checked all my provisioning profiles, certificates, reinstallation of apps. Can someone help me on this?

In my AppDelegate.Swift,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        let internet = Server.isConnectedToInternet()
        if !internet{
        }else{
            GMSServices.provideAPIKey(self.googleMapsApiKey)
            var configureError:NSError?
            GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
            assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
            self.gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
            let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GCMConfig.defaultConfig())
        }

    })
    return true
}


func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData ) {
    print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken \(deviceToken)")
    // [END receive_apns_token]
    // [START get_gcm_reg_token]
    // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
    let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
    instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
    // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
    // token to enable reception of notifications
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
    //Change kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption=true for testing and kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption=false for production
    #if DEBUG
        registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken, kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
    #else
        registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken, kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:false]
    #endif

    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    // [END get_gcm_reg_token]
}

func application( application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError ) {
    print("Registration for remote notification failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

func application( application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
    MessageHandler().handleMessage(userInfo)
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
}

func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {

    if (registrationToken != nil) {
        self.registrationToken = registrationToken
        if parent != nil{
            parent?.gcmKey = registrationToken
            parent?.saveManagedParent()
            sendGCMKeyGBox()
        }

        print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
    } else {
        print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func sendGCMKeyGBox() {
    let senderID = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).gcmSenderID!
    print(senderID)
    let params: [String:AnyObject] = [
        "appId" : (parent!.appId),
        "registrationId" : (parent!.gcmKey),
        "senderId" : senderID,
        "isAndroid" : "0"
    ]
    Server.sendPost(URL.GCMRegistration, params: params, completionHandler: sendGCMSenderIDCompletionHandler)
}
```

Above are the GCM functions I am using in AppDelegate Class.

Comment: device is registered for getting notifications?. You got device token ?

Comment: Yeah. It is registered for getting notifications. I got device token and registration token. I checked with APN Tester using device Token. It is working there and messages are coming. On connecting with backend, it is not working. And in backend, I got the success message.

Comment: @DivyaPonnuraj Are you able to receive notifications when the app is open or in background?

Comment: I want a clarification, you are using using APNS or GCM, as you saying you are using GCM for notification, but APN tool for testing?

Comment: Update your question with the code you using.

Comment: Yeah. I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109514/making-gcm-work-for-ios-device-in-the-background) if it can give you idea about your problem.

Comment: Got it. Thank you KENdi :)